# How to add sub folder in pages folder of Blazor client project

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I want to organize my pages. I added folder to pages folder of Blazor client app. and put a page in it like below. When I click on the Navlink, I only see "Sorry, there's nothing at this address."

- Pages

-TimeLogs

- Log.razor

In NavMenu.razor I have

```
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="TimeLog/log">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Time Log
        </NavLink>
    </li>
```

Log.razor is

```
@page "/log"
@using Nessie.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>put info here</h1>
```

the data can be inserted here

```
@code {
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this? This works for me. Change href to log.

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="log">
        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Time Log
    </NavLink>
</li>
```